# How many epochs should all the data be trained on after training with validation finds when validation and training diverge?

Tags: training, overfitting, epochs, validation

One uses and train/test split to use their training data to get an idea of how many epochs to train with. If the validation accuracy starts going down while the training accuracy is still going up, this would show a sign of overfitting, so one should probably stop the number epochs around there. But should training with all the data take longer to overfit? If so, should one add a few epochs? And if so for that, is there a good rule of thumb for how many? Maybe training different amounts of data could give an idea of what the differences are for number of epochs for the same amount of accuracy, even though they might not reach the same maximum amount. Any ideas on this?

Comment: Why would you train with all the data? You train the model up until the point you start to see it overfitting, and that is then the model with the parameters that you'll use to predict any new data. There is no second round of training that needs to be done.

Comment: @Oxbowerce That would mean leaving out a significant part of the data that could be used to train with to make new predictions. The validation set would give you an idea of how well the model is doing on the part of the data that is trained with, but other than that it would be wasted.

Comment: I wouldn't say it is wasted since you are using the dataset to tune your hyperparameters or see the performance of your model on out of sample data, but that would be the correct way of working since otherwise you are "leaking" information.

Comment: Yes you can use it to tune hyperparameters, but yeah too much and you get leakage. But it's still wasted in the sense that it's data that you should ultimately use it for training. Everywhere I've learned from has said to do this, but I'm just wondering if extra epochs should be used since retraining is done with more data, and if so, how much.